# Why JWT is considered as can't be managed from server?

Tags: security, jwt

I know perfectly what JWT is. But it is a known fact that there is a problem with revoking the JWT .

For example, I've read [*here*](https://medium.com/@rahulgolwalkar/pros-and-cons-in-using-jwt-json-web-tokens-196ac6d41fb4):

> We had several cases where we wanted the users at HelpTap to logout by
>   cleaning up the cookies, but we cannot ask them to do so every time. 
>   As well consider the case that a user’s mobile is stolen, and he wants
>   to logout of all existing sessions(e.g. Gmail’s logout other sessions
>   feature). Well it's not possible in case of JWT.

But if I can store the user's info in the jwt data section, then I can also create a DB in the server which will check whether a specific user should be revoked or not.

If it should, then I can send a new JWT.

**Question:**

What am I missing? I sure can revoke the specific user's JWT and send him a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can create a JWT, store it (or its JTI) in a database, and you can use the database to look up tokens and reject revoked tokens.

But the point in JWT is that it's stateless. If you have to make a database query to check it, you could just as well send your user a plain old random session id, and retrieve user data on the server side, which in fact would be more secure than any JWT. By using a database lookup, you pretty much only have the drawbacks of a JWT and a session combined, and your JWT is hardly more than just a stateful session id.

Answer (score 2):

[JWS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515) (that is, a signed [JWT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519)) relies on a *cryptographic signature* to ensure the integrity of the claims, so many application developers tend to use it to provide *stateless authentication*: if the signature is valid and the token is not expired, then the token can be trusted without depending on any state stored on the server.

That's a great and powerful approach, but it comes with a *trade-off*: it doesn't give you much control when you need to manage token revocation. So it's not a *one-size-fits-all* approach: it may work well in some contexts (such as microservices identity propagation) but it may not be suitable for all applications.

---

If you need the ability to revoke tokens, then it comes with a cost: you need to keep the track of them somewhere in your server, either in a *whitelist* or in a *blacklist*.

To achieve it, you could assign a unique identifier to each token and then store such identifier in your server. When validating the token, besides checking the signature and the expiration date, you must also check whether the token identifier is whitelisted (or is not blacklisted).

Finally, the [`jti`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.7) claim is meant for storing a unique identifier in the token:

> [**4.1.7.  "jti" (JWT ID) Claim**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.7)
>
> The `jti` (JWT ID) claim provides a unique identifier for the JWT. The identifier value MUST be assigned in a manner that ensures that there is a negligible probability that the same value will be accidentally assigned to a different data object; if the application uses multiple issuers, collisions MUST be prevented among values produced by different issuers as well.  The `jti` claim can be used to prevent the JWT from being replayed.  The `jti` value is a case-sensitive string.  Use of this claim is OPTIONAL.